# Insert a user interface in a DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll

In my project I have implemented this plugin manager:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62

In this way I can add .DLL file and make my project more modular.
I wanna know if in one of these .DLL plugin I can add a .xaml with user interface, and use it inside my main project to visualize the content of that xaml in my main GUI.
In this way I can make my app more modular not only by code library but also with user interface.

Thanks

Comment: You can, but you may find libraries like [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/) make this a lot easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a project that contains WPF UserControl items, then as long as you expose those items through the DLL interface then you can utilise them in another project.

You should be able to verify this very easily by doing something like the following:

1) Within your 'DLL' project make a public class SquareControl, which is simply a UserControl under the hood, and specifically a canvas containing a red square of a fixed size.

2) Within your utilising project, reference the DLL.

3) Within your utilising project, in C# code somewhere create an instance of SquareControl, and check in the debugger that its properties are as you expect.

4) Then create a UserControl within your utilising project, and open VS Designer for that control.  Within the empty Grid that has been created for you drop an instance of SquareControl, and you should be able to see this within Designer.  Getting your xaml namespace definitions can be awkward the first time around but there's plenty of help available for that.  Then fire up the application and see it there.